# Moving objects inside the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, svg

I want to display in a browser a web page which contains:

- a number of objects with predictable shapes (squares, rectangles etc)
- the user should have the ability to connect these objects using arrows (please see image link)

http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/6999/o33z.jpg

In addition the user should be able to move the objects, and the connecting arrows need to move with the objects so that the arrows keep point to the same objects.

Are there any current web technologies that can to that or is there one that will be a good fit to start using as a basis. I have not done any web work so even javascript might be your answer but please guide me with some specifics.

Comment: I'd recommend using HTML5 Canvas, or SVG (though there very well may be other technologies that can do this, these are the only ones I am aware of).

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: HTML5 Canvas, or SVG - I will look at those. Thanks! I have not tried anything since my knowledge is still limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Jquery UI. There's plenty of abilities in here to do what you specified above. Or you could do it using Flash/ActionScript, although that seems to be (arguably) a diminishing technology.

You can find info on how to use JueryUI here, http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Great link - thank you. Once the objects are dragable do I use javascript(?) to keep the lines attached to the objects?

Comment: You can, but JQuery and JQueryUI both will have the resources necessary to accomplish what you are looking to achieve much easier than JavaScript alone. You can get started learning these at http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/ and http://learn.jquery.com/ Once you get into it and start coding, feel free to ask specific questions on your code.

Comment: Thank you! Will look at that next.